# Change the axis scale of imshow

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm visualizing a matrix in MATLAB with `imshow`. However, I'd like the y and x axis to switch places, making x correspond to the row-index of the matrix, and y correspond to the col-index.

I also want to change the increment value of the axises to 0.01, so that row 10 has x value 0.1, row 100 has 1 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To swap the axes you will want to change the view of the axes. By default the 2D view has the y axis vertical and x axis horizontal. You can change this by rotating the [view](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) 90 degrees.

```
view(-90,90)   % Default is view(0, 90)
```

[image]

To change the increment, you will want to alter the `XData` and `YData` of the `image` object returned by `imshow`.

```
him = imshow(img, []);
set(him, 'XData', [0, size(img, 2)/100], 'YData', [0, size(img, 1)/100]);
```

[image]