# Is there a way to plot Matplotlib's Imshow against a specific array rather than the indices?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 2d, fft

I'm trying to use Imshow to plot a 2-d Fourier transform of my data. However, Imshow plots the data against its index in the array. I would like to plot the data against a set of arrays I have containing the corresponding frequency values (one array for each dim), but can't figure out how.

I have a 2D array of data (gaussian pulse signal) that I Fourier transform with np.fft.fft2. This all works fine. I then get the corresponding frequency bins for each dimension with np.fft.fftfreq(len(data))*sampling_rate. I can't figure out how to use imshow to plot the data against these frequencies though. The 1D equivalent of what I'm trying to do us using plt.plot(x,y) rather than just using plt.plot(y).

My first attempt was to use imshows "extent" flag, but as fas as I can tell that just changes the axis limits, not the actual bins.

My next solution was to use np.fft.fftshift to arrange the data in numerical order and then simply re-scale the axis using this answer: [Change the axis scale of imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946466/change-the-axis-scale-of-imshow). However, the index to frequency bin is not a pure scaling factor, there's typically a constant offset as well.

My attempt was to use 2d hist instead of imshow, but that doesn't work since 2dhist plots the number of times an order pair occurs, while I want to plot a scalar value corresponding to specific order pairs (i.e the power of the signal at specific frequency combinations).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

f = 200
st = 2500
x = np.linspace(-1,1,2*st)
y = signal.gausspulse(x, fc=f, bw=0.05)

data = np.outer(np.ones(len(y)),y) # A simple example with constant y

Fdata = np.abs(np.fft.fft2(data))**2

freqx = np.fft.fftfreq(len(x))*st # What I want to plot my data      against
freqy = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y))*st

plt.imshow(Fdata)
```

I should see a peak at (200,0) corresponding to the frequency of my signal (with some fall off around it corresponding to bandwidth), but instead my maximum occurs at some random position corresponding to the frequencie's index in my data array. If anyone has any idea, fixes, or other functions to use I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to SO! your example code has a syntax error in line 8 (`)` missing). Even when fixing it, I still get `ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32` when running your code. Not entirely sure what youre trying to do. Would  help to supply the plot you're getting as well as the desired outcome (with paint if neccessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot run your code, but I think you are looking for the [`extent=` argument to `imshow()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-imshow). See the [the page on `origin` and `extent`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html) for more information.

Something like this may work?

```
plt.imshow(Fdata, extent=(freqx[0],freqx[-1],freqy[0],freqy[-1]))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting the error (I just ran the code myself) but regardless, it looks like that works. Thank you very much for the link! It made it a lot more obvious than the standard documentation.